# Windows 8.1 - Add an unavailable network

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, network-profiles

In Win8.1 it seems like I can only connect to SSIDs that are within my range of access. Say I had a computer that I needed to set up to connect to a network with wifi somewhere else.

**How do I set up a network profile connecting to an SSID that is not available at the computer's location?**

EDIT: [Here's an example](http://kb.netgear.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/20089/~/how-to-manually-add-a-wireless-network-in-windows-7-and-vista) of how to do this on Windows Vista / Windows 7, but it's no longer available on Windows 8

Comment: I deleted my answer because I was incorrect about not being able to do this in Win7. You're right; Win8 seems to have lost this ability. I don't know how Win7 accomplished the WPA hash without knowing the BSSID of the AP (maybe it saved it somewhere and supplied it dynamically when it sees the network for the first time?).  My apologies for steering you in the wrong direction.

Comment: Well, it did provide good information though. My guess is that win7 simply keeps the information until it finds an SSID with the matching name and information... but I could be wrong.